# Rails input form got populated with jQuery .val(), however data is not present in params

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to populate a field in a Rails form with a javascript variable.

This is the code:

---

View

```
= form_for @post do |f|
  = f.text_area :hello
  = f.submit class: "savebtn"
```

Controller

```
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  ...
end
```

JavaScript

```
var $save = $('.savebtn');

$save.on('click', function(e) {
  var someVar = "hey!";
  $('#post_hello').val(someVar);
});
```

I can see for an instant how the text area got populated. However, the data "never" arrives in params. I checked that by raising something in the controller action, like this:

```
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  raise '¯\_(ツ)_/¯'
  ...
end
```

post_params

```
{"hello"=>""}
```

However, if I put manually the same data, it works just fine.

What I'm missing? Is there a better approach? (aside the fact that this is not working, yet)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you adding the input value in JavaScript when the form submit button is clicked?

Comment: Try inserting the values before the click event, maybe **onBeforeUnload**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try populate the value in the form's submit event instead of the click event

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
  var someVar = "hey!";
  $('#post_hello').val(someVar);
})
```